# How can I use excel to create a multiple IF function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet comparing numbers of programmes sold by my company. I want to create a formula that will total several variables.

In one column I have the month then whether it is a "Finance" or an "Enterprise" programme, then I have the number of minutes sold. I want to create a formula for each month telling me how many minutes of each programme were sold.

e.g. in September we sold 200 minutes of Enterprise programmes.

How can I create a formula to do this when 3 columns are involved?

Comment: You can use nested If statements. But reading your question carefully you seem to have it all in one cell, maybe if you could show some of your data or how it is arranged.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have the month in column A, the type of programme in column B and the minutes in column C, you can use `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, "September", B:B, "Enterprise")
```

Put the formula in any cell that is not in columns A, B or C, or you'll likely get a circular reference warning.

Comment: You can put the formula field in the A,B,C column if you specify a range instead of just a column like so: `=SUMIFS(C1:C31, A1:A31, "September", B1:B31, "Enterprise")`. Just make sure to put your formula below row 31.

Comment: @Linger Indeed, but since we weren't given the height of the table, I felt it safer taking the whole column!